# How do I make a shape key using a rig menu?

Tags: rigging, shape-keys

I have a minecraft character rig, and it uses a menu, where you can edit the face expressions. You move the little box around, and it edits the mesh. How can I use this with creating shape keys for my lip-sync? Is there a way to do this, without editing the mesh slowly in edit mode, using the rig?

[image]

Comment: I am not completely sure what you want, but if you want to know how to make the menu, then you add a shape key to the mesh, go into edit mode, pull some points to edit it how you want to, then go out of edit mode. Then add a driver to the shape key to hook it up to a bone, then add a custom shape to the bone. or you could hook it up to a object instead of a bone.

Comment: Thanks, I'll upload a picture, because I cant edit the menu thing in edit mode.